# Executing a function on multiple data sets

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

Is there an easy solution on executing a function on several objects? I was experimenting with `do.call` and `sapply` but didn't got it to run.

I have 3 data frames and I am checking the number of rows for them. To get a vector I am using `c(nrow(df), nrow(df_flt), nrow(df_ident))`. The results would be the plain vector showing the numbers. What I would love to get is a named vector like this by calling something like:

```
do.my.call(nrow, c(df, df_flt, df_ident))

  nrow(df)   nrow(df_flt) nrow(df_ident) 
        95             58              3
```

Is there a way to get this named vector with a single line of code? I could construct a function on my own, at the moment I have just the feeling this should be possible by using build in functions

Here is some example data.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:95)
df_flt <- df[1:58,]
df_ident <- df[1:3,]
c(nrow(df), nrow(df_flt), nrow(df_ident))

jnk <- c(nrow(df), nrow(df_flt), nrow(df_ident))
names(jnk) <- c('nrow(df)', 'nrow(df_flt)', 'nrow(df_ident)')
```

Comment: Put them in a list then lapply with nrow, e.g.: `lapply(list(mtcars, mtcars), nrow)`

Comment: Is there a way to get the names on of the calls or the names of the data sets?

Comment: Maybe this: `sapply(list(mtcars = mtcars, cars = cars), nrow)` ?

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't thought about naming the list... This is what I was looking for! perfect. Please feel free to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can put them into a named list then use `apply`:

```
sapply(list(mtcars = mtcars, cars = cars), nrow)

# mtcars   cars 
#     32     50
```